# Android Styles don't work correctly in API < 21

Tags: android

I have a problem with styles in API < 21. I think this might be related to the configuration of backgroundTint and foregroundTint because some backgrounds of a cardView are setted this way "?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" (using ?android:attr ~) but i'm not sure.

My problem looks like this:
[https://s31.postimg.org/rnmmt6tvv/background_tint.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpaeE.png)

I tried to change the values in API 19 with editor but i can't.

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_catafeira_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.SolidActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.AboutActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.AboutActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkAbout</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Widget.AboutActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

style.xml(v21)

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_catafeira_light</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I'm using targetApi 23. How can i fix this problem without set the backgrounds manually?
Sorry for my english, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

BackgroundTint didn't exist in API 19.  It was added with API 21.  You can't change it in API 19 because it doesn't exist there.  If you need that functionality in v19, you need to either use a support library or do it some other way.

Comment: Thanks, do u know some support library to suggest?

Comment: The normal support library has DrawableCompat.  You'll need some code to make it work, but it does tinting.